# Switching to Intel C++ 16.0 in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel

I've installed Intel C++ compiler 16.0 in my recent project. I followed all the instructions in [Using the Intel C++](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581640). However I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\amprt.h(455): error : expected a ";"
_Buffer_descriptor() __GPU
                     ^  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\amprt.h(576): error : expected a ";"
_Texture_descriptor() __GPU
                      ^
```

I am also using Eigen library in my code for matrix multiplication. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Don't use AMP, that is a Microsoft specific library.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. Solved the issue!